# how can i fetch account details from just a "admob id"

Tags: iphone, ios, admob

I recently publish an app on Apple app store, which had admob integrated into it for displaying adds. As i was not the sole developer of app, it was done by some one else.

Now, as app is already in the store, and adds are popping up and being clicked, revenue must be going somewhere, but not in my account as i never provided any credit card details.

Upon searching through code, i was able to get a "Admob id". It think this is what google uses to manage all revenue and advertisement system.

Now i want to know who is linked to this Admob id. Or any other detail that i can fetch from just a "Admob id".

Comment: You should use the Id generated from your account if you use add id of other people then revenue will into their account. Change The Id and you can see revenue in your account.

Comment: yes that i can, but i want track details regd. the person who has been getting revenue till now

Comment: go to the account in which the ID was created. If you don't know then you can't track.